# Shooting causes controller to turn off

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

How do you fix the bug in GTA V that when you shoot with any character your controller turns off? I'm on XBOX 360 by the way. I can't advance in the game because every time I shoot or bump into something in my car, my controller turns off. This all started when I unlocked Trevor.

Answer (score 2):

your batteries might be low. Does charging/replacing them fix it? 
if not replace the controller it self. :)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you don't have any magnets near the Xbox or the controller.

Comment: This seems _extremely_ unlikely for a number of reasons.  I also don't see how a magnet would cause a controller to turn off.